# Whenever I build a project on android studio, OpenJDK platform binary is taking so much ram and build time is also increased

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, java-17

My gradle version is 8.3.0
Android studio version - Iguana
On building the project, every time the build is taking more time.
[Open Jdk is taking around 2 to 3 gb of ram, sometimes more than android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cqaz.png)

Switching wireless hotspot off is also not working